# geom_tile and geom_text and facet_wrap produce incorrect confusion matrices

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data frame is looks like this:

```
method1 = c("cam","sce","cam","sce","cam","sce","cam","sce","cam","sce","cam","sce","cam","sce","cam","sce");
method2 = c("cam","cam","sce","sce","cam","cam","sce","sce","cam","cam","sce","sce","cam","cam","sce","sce");
p = c(0,0.191781,0.780822,0,0,0.082192,0.890411,0,0,0.383562,0.616438,0,0,0.054795,0.863014,0);
participant = c("LucO","LucO","LucO","LucO","ad","ad","ad","ad","arthur","arthur","arthur","arthur","evgeny","evgeny","evgeny","evgeny");
mydata = data.frame(method1,method2,p,participant);
```

I am trying to plot the confusion matrix of each participant as:

```
p <- ggplot( mydata, aes( x=method1, y=method2, fill=method2 ) ) + 
     geom_tile( aes( fill = mydata$p ) ) +
     geom_text( aes( fill = mydata$p, label = round( mydata$p, 3 ) * 100 ) ) +
     facet_wrap( ~participant, ncol=3, scales="free_x" );
```

However, now for each `participant` the wrong confusion matrix is plotted. Could you please help me fix this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just lose `mydata$p` and add just `p` and it will be fine.

The correct call of the function is:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot( mydata, aes( x=method1, y=method2, fill=method2 ) ) + 
  geom_tile( aes( fill = p ) ) +
  geom_text( aes( fill = p, label = round( p, 3 ) * 100 ) ) +
  facet_wrap( ~participant, ncol=3, scales="free_x" );
p
```

Output:

[image]

Data (for comparison against the graph)

```
> mydata
   method1 method2        p participant
1      cam     cam 0.000000        LucO
2      sce     cam 0.191781        LucO
3      cam     sce 0.780822        LucO
4      sce     sce 0.000000        LucO
5      cam     cam 0.000000          ad
6      sce     cam 0.082192          ad
7      cam     sce 0.890411          ad
8      sce     sce 0.000000          ad
9      cam     cam 0.000000      arthur
10     sce     cam 0.383562      arthur
11     cam     sce 0.616438      arthur
12     sce     sce 0.000000      arthur
13     cam     cam 0.000000      evgeny
14     sce     cam 0.054795      evgeny
15     cam     sce 0.863014      evgeny
16     sce     sce 0.000000      evgeny
```